# LLVM how to do AOT compilation

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to create a toy language with LLVM

Currently, i'm able to emit a file with my LLVM IR, but I don't know how to statically compile it into an executable. The LLVM tutorial uses JIT compilation, but I want to do AOT compilation.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `llc` on your `.ll` file. It'll give you the assembly file. You could then use  an assembler like `as`to get the final executable. With `llc` you can specify the architecture you want. `llc --version` gives you a list of supported architectures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've generated LLVM IR, you can firstly code generate the IR to machine code by LLC and then link the object file to the executable.

If you want to use it by the command line, things goes easy just by

```
clang yourIRFile.ll -o output
```

or

```
llc yourIRFile.ll --filetype=obj
lld generatedObjFileName.o -o output
```

Otherwise, you could use the `llc` and `lld` api.
( the following key code are extracted from `llc.cpp` and `lld.cpp` from its tools directory, and all codes are verified by myself )

Firstly, for code gen, use the `target machine pass` by

```
legacy::PassManager pass;
auto CPU = "generic";
auto Features = "";
std::string Error;
auto Target = TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(module->getTargetTriple(), Error);
TheTargetMachine =
        Target->createTargetMachine(module->getTargetTriple(), CPU, Features, targetOptions, RM);
assert(TheTargetMachine && "Fail to create TheTargetMachine");

auto FileType = CGFT_ObjectFile;
SmallVector<char, 0> objStream;
std::unique_ptr<raw_svector_ostream> BOS = std::make_unique<raw_svector_ostream>(objStream);
auto OS = BOS.get();
if (TheTargetMachine->addPassesToEmitFile(pass, *OS, nullptr, FileType)) {
    errs() << "TheTargetMachine can't emit a file of this type";
    return;
}

// Here write the `objStream` content to a temp file you like.
// the objStream is the object file need by lld linker
```

then use the lld linker

```
const char *emu_argv[] = {
        "ld.lld",
        objFileName,
        "-o",
        execFileName,
};
int argc = sizeof(emu_argv) / sizeof(emu_argv[0]);
const char **argv = (const char **) emu_argv;
std::vector<const char *> args(argv, argv + argc);
lld::elf::link(args, false, outs(), outs());
```

the `objFileName` is the file which you generated at codegen.
Finally, the `execFileName` is the final executable file.

Comment: how can i use `lld::elf::link` -- what file do i include

Comment: include `<lld/Common/Driver.h>`. And make sure you have installed the `lld` or compiled it.